# ' ValueError: too many values to unpack '

Tags: python, nested-lists, minesweeper

I'm trying to write a basic version of minesweeper.You get the number of rows,  columns ,bombs and their location from the user. you should count number of bombs surrounding each element. consider the example below:
input

```
4 3
5
1 1
4 3
1 3
4 2
3 2
```

output is:

```
* 2 *
2 3 2
2 * 3
2 * *
```

Here's my code:

```
n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]


k = int(input()) #number of bombs

#location of bombs
bomb = []
for i in range(k):
    r,c = [int(r) - 1 for r in input().split()]
    bomb.append([r,c])

#making the grid
map = []
for x in range(n):
    map.append([])
    for y in range(m):
        map[x].append(0)

#locate bombs       
for i, j in bomb:
    map[i][j] = '*'

#count the bombs
Ns = 0
for i, j in map:
    for x in range(-1, 2):
        for y in range(-1, 2):
            if map[i + x][j + y] == '*':
                Ns += 1

    map[i][j] = Ns

print(map)
```

My problem is finding bombs in surrendering. I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack for line 25`. Any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Format the code properly.. Btw, here ```n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split()] ``` you are having a list comps on the rhs which will give you a single value of type list.. You are trying to unpack it to 2 variables which is not possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `input()` accepts a parameter prompt. It's important to use it, otherwise the user will have no idea what to enter: `input("please enter two numbers (rows, columns)")` etc. It's a good idea to add error handling for malformed input and generally create a pleasant UX. The code redefines the internal `map` function--pick another variable name. (This is in addition to Sam's remark).

Comment: shadi : You should give the input that trigger the error. As @SamDaniel pointed, the first line triggers the error if it is passed a single int. It is ok if if receives 2 values. The usage of your code is not obvious on first sight.  Also when giving a python error, tell us which line ; it'll make everything easier.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your code is not minimal; why is there all of this input and set-up code in the way, when the error involves three variables on line 24?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in map:
```

is invalid.  `map` is a list of lists, something akin to a 4x3 array.

You seem to be trying to iterate through the indices of `map`, and have confused those with the list contents.  Try

```
for i in range(len(map)):
    for j in range(len(map[i])):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two potential problems in your code.

Firstly, your map actually has 3 values to unpack for each value (since your m is 3), rather than two. This is the line that you need to fix:

`for i, j in map:`

Instead, what you need is probably to unpack each value for map, like so:

```
for x in range(len(map)):
    for y in range(len(map[i])):
        square = map[x][y]
```

Secondly, your code for checking the surroundings can run into issues because you simply decrement/increment the x and y of the mine by 1, this will make your code try to find indexes in the map that doesn't exist! Eg. if x is 2, incrementing by 1 will give you 3, breaking your list.

What you probably want is:

```
for i in range(max(0,x-1),min(x+1,n-1)+1):
    for j in range(max(0,y-1),min(y+1,m-1)+1):
```

This only takes in the values that are both in the surroundings, and do not violate the array bounds. Max(0, x-1) prevents us from giving negative array bounds, and min(x+1, n-1) prevents us from going over the max array bounds. Similarly so for y.

Combined, the code would probably look something like this:

```
#count the bombs
for x in range(len(map)):
    for y in range(len(map[i])):
        # if x,y is not a mine
        if map[x][y] != '*':
            # check the surroundings of x,y for mines
            Ns = 0
            for i in range(max(0,x-1),min(x+1,n-1)+1):
                for j in range(max(0,y-1),min(y+1,m-1)+1):
                    # if this surrounding block is a mine, add to Ns
                    if (map[i][j]) == '*':
                        Ns += 1
                        print("Not safe: " + str(Ns))
            # append the Ns number to the x,y block
            map[x][y] = Ns

for layer in map:
    print(layer)
```

Outputs:

```
['*', 2, '*']
[2, 3, 2]
[2, '*', 3]
[2, '*', '*']
```

Note that this is definitely not the most optimized solution for the problem; the best way is to save values as we go along so we don't have to check all the 3 to 8 surrounding tiles for **every** tile, but hopefully this helps you understand the base case for dealing with minesweeper.

Hope that helps!